# Generating quadrilateral mesh from Mathematica surface mesh

Tags: algorithm, wolfram-mathematica, geometry, mesh

I am trying to make a quadrilateral mesh from a surface mesh (which is mostly triangular) generated by Mathematica. I am not looking for high quality mesher but a simple work around algorithm. I use [GMSH](http://geuz.org/gmsh/) for doing it externally. We can make use of Mathematic's CAD import capabilities to generate 3D geometries that are understood by the Mathematica kernel.

We can see the imported `Geometry3D` objects and the plots of number of sides in each polygons they consist of. It become visible that the polygons that form the mesh are not always triangles.

```
Name3D=RandomChoice[ExampleData["Geometry3D"][[All,2]],6];
AllPic=
  Table[
  Vertex=ExampleData[{"Geometry3D",Name3D[[i]]},"VertexData"];
  Polygons=ExampleData[{"Geometry3D",Name3D[[i]]},"PolygonData"];
  GraphicsGrid[
  {{ListPlot[#,Frame-> True,PlotLabel->Name3D[[i]] ]&@(Length[#]&/@Polygons),
  Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[Vertex,Polygon[Polygons]],Boxed-> False]}}
  ,ImageSize-> 300,Spacings-> {0,0}],
  {i,1,Length@Name3D}];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[AllPic,2],Spacings-> {0,0}]
```

[image]

Now what I am looking for is an algorithm to form a quadrilateral mesh from that polygon information available to MMA. Any easy solution is very much welcome. By easy solution I mean which is not going to work in a very general setting (where mesh constitutes of polygons with sides more than 5 or 6) and which might be quite inefficient compared to commercial software. But one can see that there are not many quadrilateral surface mesh generator available other than few expensive commercial one.

BR

Comment: Are you looking for a full mesh (hexahedra/bricks) or a surface mesh (quads)? How do you want to deal with triangles that look like this: Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0, 0.5}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
  Polygon[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 1}}]]] - propably you'd need a normal test. And what to do with intersecting triangles like shown at the bottom of http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/tutorial/UsingTetGenLink.html. The "SpaceShuttle" is watertight.. Could you upload a picture of a result done with GMSH of, say, the cow?

Comment: If you want the quad surface the qmorph algorithm could be a basis: pages.cs.wisc.edu/~csverma/CS899_09/qmorph.pdf

Comment: Are you considering solutions like removing the shared side from a two-triangle set?

Comment: @belisarius Yes this is one of the crudest way to go. As ruebenko pointed out qmorph is a well know algorithm that requires quite lot of work in MMA. I want something simple likewise you said. I will update the question once I have a better example with the cow and how to use GMSH to generate quadmesh. I need little more time as I currently busy with something else. I hope you find the problem interesting.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you going to do with the mesh?

Comment: I think I saw something like that done by using the [IMTEK package] (http://portal.uni-freiburg.de/imteksimulation/downloads/ims), but that was long ago and I could be wrong

Comment: Yes, that project was a long time ago. Seen that Mathematica now has a TetGenLink you could do the mesh stuff from the IMS much more efficiently. @belisrius, it is always nice to hear the some people found it useful for some things.

Comment: I don't know why the IMTEK was not updated with Mathematica. It is a gem of a tool. I also like IMS more than the current TetGEnLink. Mesh manipulation is easier in IMTEK.

Comment: The IMS was not updated because I did not find the time to do that. If there are sufficient requests from enough people I might reconsider that. The current TetGenLink is a very low level interface - the point of that interface is that it outperforms the IMS file based interface by far. This is needed for any serious subsequent work with Tetrahedralizations.

Answer (score 0):

this will produce quads regardless of the input topology:

- insert one vertex in the center of each face
- insert one vertex at the midpoint of each edge
- insert edges connecting each face's center vertex with it's edges' midpoint vertices